# Adding Images to a ListView

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I've got a listview populated from a sqlite database and works fine, but I want a picture to be fill in next to the text.

So at the moment the ListView shows the characters names. I want to get another field if that field equals x set picture x else if that field equal y shows picture y.

Can I add images with my current implementation?

```
listContent = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.contentlist);
mDbAdapter = new DbAdapter(this);
mDbAdapter.open();
Cursor cursor = mDbAdapter.fetchAll();
startManagingCursor(cursor);
String[] from = new String[] { DbAdapter.KEY_NAME };
int[] to = new int[] { R.id.text };
cursorAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);
mDbAdapter.close();
```

And heres the xml

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:text="Name"
    android:paddingLeft="10dip"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:padding="5dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation for [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) you cannot bind images to views using from and to method in that constructor. But you can easily accomplish what you are looking to do by extending [SimpleCursorAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) and overriding [getViewBinder()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#getViewBinder%28%29) to return your own [ViewBinder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder.html). Your ViewBinder should handle reading the current row and binding the text to the view as well as your image.